# log in to the system after authenticating the user

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername="localhost";
$susername="root";
$spassword="";
$dbname="testdb";
$unerr=$pserr=$derror="";
$_username=$_password=$_repassword=$_email="";
$username=$password="";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
if(empty($_POST["username"]))
{
$unerr="Username Required";
}
else{
$username=$_POST["username"];

}

if(empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$pserr="password Required";
}
else{
$password=$_POST["password"];
$hashed_password=crypt($password);

}


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $susername, $spassword, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
 $query1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'       AND password='$_password'");
$numrows=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
if($numrows['username']=$username && $numrows['password']=$hashed_password)
{
    $_SESSION['userlogin'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['userpassword']=$password;
    header('Location: homepage.php');


 }
 else{
    $derror="Invalid Username or Password";
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

The problem with this is that whenever i enter some random details the user is still able to log in to the system.
no message is shown when i enter a username which is not inside the table.
how can i validate? if the user does not exist in the db table?

Comment: if the user does not exist in the db table?: yes, that would be a good start :)

Comment: You're using assignments in your value check instead of checking equality. I.e. `=` instead of `==` / `===`.

Comment: As @JonStirling it should have been `$numrows['username']===$username && $numrows['password']===$hashed_password`

Comment: yes thanx ! but now even invalid username or password is shown when i enter valid user details

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to change the line 40 :

From :

```
if($numrows['username']=$username && $numrows['password']=$hashed_password)
```

To :

```
if($numrows['username']==$username && $numrows['password']==$hashed_password)
```

'=' Is for an assignement / $i = 1 --> We set the value of $i to 1

'==' Is for a comparaison / if($i == 1) --> We check if $i is equal to 1

You should also take a look at this doc :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 0):

what is $_password and is there clear password or hashed password in ur db.
if you have hashed password in your db you should do this

```
$query1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
if($numrows['username']==$username && $numrows['password']==$hashed_password);
```

Comment: yes is did try that but users are not able to login now

Answer (score 0):

Some Fixes to your problem:

1) Use [mysqli_num_rows](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp) function to check if the user with provided username and password exist or not.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query1) == 1)
{
    //rest of the stuff
}
```

2) Use `==` or `===` for equality check rather that `=`

3) **But** if you fire query such that

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' 
AND password='$hashed_password'");
```

it will give you more accurate result. There will not be any need of `if($numrows['username']==$username && $numrows['password']==$hashed_password)`

Comment: try some debugging my friend. what number of rows is it returning? try echoing the query and fire it directly in phpmyadmin and see the results....